# Logical Scrolling without Virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, virtualization, scrollviewer

Is it possible, to make a logical scrolling (per item) while turning virtualization off? The problem I have is that when I open new tabitems and they are outside of visible area, their content aren't refreshing(rendering) until I scroll to them (because of virtualization). Changing **CanContentScroll** to **false** in ScrollViewer helps with that, but I don't want to loose logical scrolling.

I tried switching to stackpanel - but then scrollViewer kinda breaks. With TabPanel logical scroll doesnt work at all and keeps scrolling by pixel. I figured that VirtualizingStackPanel is the best solution.. but i dont need virtualization.

```
<ScrollViewer
                 x:Name="sv"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 CanContentScroll="True"
                 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
<VirtualizingStackPanel
                  Orientation="Horizontal"
                  x:Name="headerPanel"
                  Panel.ZIndex="1"
                  IsItemsHost="true"
                  KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```